# jQuery How to get in to a specific div without any animation when viewing the page in mobile device

Tags: jquery

I need help about this.

I have a mobile lander with a Polaroid image on the header. But I wanted to automatically view the 5step form under the polaroid image when I view it on my mobile without any animation or something.

Please let me know how can I achieve this idea. Thank you

Comment: Hm. What's 5step?

Comment: Here is the first reference you need: [ask].

Comment: @jkris 5 step form for submission of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since u tagged JQuery, here's an example you could follow:

https://www.abeautifulsite.net/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin-2

Pretty straight forward use, that's provided all elements are not hidden and within the same page

```
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $("#STEP5-FORM").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

**EDIT**

Without animation, simply use the [`scrollTop`](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) api by jquery

```
$('html, body').scrollTop($("#STEP5-FORM").offset().top);
```

Comment: is there any way that there will be no animation included? i mean when you open the page on your mobile device, it will automatically go to its specific div which is the 5step form.?

Comment: thank you so much!! your code is working! appreciated your help!